# How can i solve this issue "show product quantity in stock respect to size" in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have install **woocommerce plugin** and wanted to show product quantity with respect to size in this way on product page like **large:15 and small:13 in stock**
wordpress version is 4.4.2
so please guide me how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. WordPress and the plugin WooCommerce provides you an option where you can add products and specially skins for your products. You can fiind it on Settings > WooCommerce and Add Product. Otherwise, you can add a new entry in your site for add a costum product. Also you can install and make custom fields for Woocommerce products with this plugin https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/